# Using ATTiny84 digital output pins

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, integrated-circuit, attiny

Is there anything special (like set fuses or register values) I have to do to be able to the following pins as digital IO on the ATTiny84?

- PA0 to PA3
- PA7
- PB2

I thought I could use the RESET pin but after reading the datasheet I found out I couldn't, so I'm trying to avoid any other gotchas that I might have missed in the datasheet. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: the  only source that we have is the table in the datasheet with the alternative settings, and the exact picture you've posted.

Comment: Sure, I'm more looking for confirmation from people who have more experience in this than me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Nothing special needs doing.

---

All IO pins with the exception of the Reset signal can be general purpose digital IO.

The reset signal *can* be used as digital input, however in order to do so you have to disable ISP in the fuses meaning only high-voltage programming can be used to recover the chip. I would advise against using it if you can avoid it.

---

The ISP pins PA4, PA5, and PA6 can be used as GPIO without disabling programming, hence the name In-Circuit Programming. A little bit of care is needed to make sure that your circuit doesn't interfere with programing capabilities.

If you use the ISP pins for things like push buttons or LEDs, you don't need any extra circuitry as these won't affect the programmer.

The simplest solution for connecting to external hardware to this is to just add jumpers (either solder or pin header) between the rest of the circuit and the MCU - you can then disconnect your circuit to prevent any interference with the programmer.

Comment: Thanks! Like you said, I decided not to interfere with PA4-6 and RESET just because I need those for ISP, I think (CMIIW).

Comment: @AnubhavSrivastava I've added a bit about the ISP pins - these can be used while still allowing programming as long as you take care.